# Calendar App Sorts by Reverse Alphabetical

Tags: calendar, user-interface

Why are the events for a given day in the calendar app sorted by reverse alphabetical? Shouldn't it be sorted by start time? That seems pretty standard with calendar apps.

From looking at the code, there does not seem to be a way to change this with configuration.